# Zend Framework: How to attach other than default layout

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have created  a module 'admin' . I also created a layout for this admin module. How can I permanently attach this layout to 'admin' module. Can some one suggest me where and how can I write code for this purpose. Whether it would be in bootstrap file ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a module like you say you can simply add a layout.phtml file into the module's layout/scripts/ folder.

If you have a different name for your layout.phtml like admin.phtml you simple add the following in your controller

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('admin');
```

It should and will check first the module's layout folder and then the default folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify alternative path for layout scripts:

```
if (!$registered) {
//for PUBLIC role
  Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayoutPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/layouts/scripts/pub');
} else {
//For registered users
  Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayoutPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/layouts/scripts');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap file

```
protected function _initAutoloader() {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default'), array(
            'namespace' => 'Admin',
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin'
        )            
      );
      return $autoloader;

    }
```

application.ini

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
appnamespace = "Default"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.frontController.defaultController = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.modules = ""
resources.view[] =
```

and in each controller of admin you need to add this line to the init function to change the layout.

$this->_helper->layout()->setLayout("admin");